Comparing regression coefficients across non-nested SEM models (Lavaan)
I had question about SEM in Lavaan which I cannot seem to get a grip on through any google forums or my old lecture slides... I wish to explain cognition using several variables (CR1/CR2, which stand for different cognitive reserve measures) yet in separate models. The models are non-nested, they have the same latent outcome variable, but have different predictor variables to predict the outcome (in my case cognition)- like this:
model_CR1  <- '
cognition =~ x1+x2+x3
CR1 =~ y2
cognition ~ CR1
'

and this:
model_CR2 <- '
cognition  =~ x1+x2+x3
CR2  =~ y1+y3+y4
cognition ~ CR2
'

See how the CR1 and CR2 variables have entirely different observed variables and one of them only consists of 1 observed variable while the other is based on three. I realize I cannot compare the full model indices (like AIC or RMSEA) because the models are non-nested and have a different  DFs, but can I directly compare the regression variables from cognition ~ CR1 / cognition ~ CR2 using the standardized coefficients or is this inappropriate too?
I'd be very grateful for your advice!

Both structural models are simple regressions (cognition ~ CR1).  I'm not sure why you wouldn't just run a multiple regression including both CR measures.  Regardless, it is not clear what you mean by "comparable."

Because neither construct (CR nor cognition) is a simple sumscore. They are latent constructs that are formed by several indicator variables.
I mean that I wish to compare the effects of CR1 and CR2 on cognition in two separate models, yet as CR1 is simple (only has 1 indicator variable) whereas CR 2 is more complex (3 indicator variables) I do not know whether this is possible, since the models would have different DFs and a different covariance structure.


can I directly compare the regression variables from cognition ~ CR1 / cognition ~ CR2 using the standardized coefficients

It depends what you mean by "compare".  If the CR1 and CR2 indicators are on the same scale (e.g., 5-point Likert scale?), then their unstandardized effects on cognition can be comparable if you work with composites.  That is, average the 3 indicators of CR2 to obtain a composite that has the same scale as CR1.  But for the unstandardized cognition~CR1 and cognition~CR2 coefficients to be directly comparable in terms of magnitude, you would also need to calculate a composite for cognition.  Otherwise, the latent scale of cognition is not really comparable across models.  This is the same phenomenon Paul Allison (1999) described for comparing logistic/probit regression coefficients across models, but in that case it is about the arbitrary scaling of the latent response underlying the binary/ordinal outcome, whereas in this case it is about the arbitrary scaling of a common factor.
Even if you use composites of CR that are on the same scale (and a composite for cognition, so its scale is not arbitrary), you still couldn't statistically test equivalence of CR slopes when they come from different models, unless you use bootstrapping to obtain an empirically estimated sampling distribution (and CI) for their difference.
If the CR1 and CR2 indicators are on different scales, then comparing standardized coefficients is not really a solution because those are not really "scale free".  Two predictors might have the same effect but different variances, making the standardized effect different (i.e., differences in effect are confounded with differences in scale).  Gary King's (1986) critique is still relevant to read today.

the models are non-nested and have a different DFs

They can be non-nested even with the same df.  But consider that using OLS regression (with fixed effects) both models are nested under the more general model that includes both predictors.  From this perspective, you could test the $H_0$ that the effect of one CR is redundant with the other CR's effect.  Rejecting either $H_0$ implies that CR's effect (controlling for the other CR) is nonzero.
SEM is an analysis of covariance structure, so the df are based on the number of observed (co)variances, not rows of data.  Thus, a general "parent" SEM that includes both of these as a special case must includes all variables:
model_gen  <- '
  cognition =~ x1 + x2 + x3
        CR1 =~ y2
        CR2 =~ y1 + y3 + y4

  cognition ~ CR1 + CR2
'
fit_gen <- sem(model_gen, data = ...)

Then each nested model needs to include all the same terms, but specifying one CR's effect at a time to be 0:
model_CR1  <- '
  cognition =~ x1 + x2 + x3
        CR1 =~ y2
        CR2 =~ y1 + y3 + y4

  cognition ~ CR1 + 0*CR2
'

model_CR2 <- '
  cognition =~ x1 + x2 + x3
        CR1 =~ y2
        CR2 =~ y1 + y3 + y4

  cognition ~ 0*CR1 + CR2
'

Then you can call lavTestLRT() twice, to compare the fitted general model to each of the nested model.  Or you can simply use the asymptotically equivalent Wald z tests of the slopes in the general model's summary().
Just one more idea:
If CR1 and CR2 are both measuring the same construct, it might make sense to treat all 4 indicators as being outcomes of the same factor.
model_CR  <- '
  cognition =~ x1 + x2 + x3
         CR =~ y1 + y2 + y3 + y4

  cognition ~ CR
'


Thanks you for your helpful reply. CR1 / CR2 will be on different scales and the cognition part will comprise of three latent constructs (I simplified the example). So, I think your solution of creating a parent model is really useful. Do I understand correctly, that if they are both significant, I could constrain the regression coefficients to be exactly the same (so: cognition ~ CR1a, cognitionCR2a) to test whether they are significantly different from eachother?
The last solution might be tricky, because one component of CR1 (y1) is highly correlated to CR2 (but measured differently).

I think you mean cognition ~ a*CR1 + a*CR2 to equality-constrain the slopes.  That is possible, but only makes sense if CR1 and CR2 have the same scale (i.e., if a 1-unit increase in X means the same thing for both Xs).
